# How to get mock final classes mock-maker-inline to work?

Tags: mockito, final-class

I'm having issue getting the mock-maker-inline to work.  I followed the instructions on

[image]

However, i still can't mock out a final class.  I also tried out the example in the document.  I was wondering if there is anyway to debug what went wrong?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class Tests$1FinalClass
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

I'm on `mockito org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0` and using

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: You might want to add some information about your project structure and where you created the file. Works for me, if you leave out the `resources` folder and put the `mockito-extensions` folder directly into the `test source` folder.

Comment: I had similar issue, but making use of PowerMockito and  turning on mock-maker-inline as specified in this link https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/blob/master/mockito2/src/test/resources/org/powermock/extensions/configuration.properties
 helped me